# Custom URL Scheme Failing within own app

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a custom URL scheme that I've been using successfully in my app during development for a few months now. We have some web pages that we load in some `WKWebViews`, and some of those links use our custom URL scheme to call our own app, which then takes action based on those URLs.

Today I deleted the app on my phone and reinstalled it in an attempt to work out a different bug I was having.

Suddenly, tapping on these links does *nothing*. I cannot find an error being thrown anywhere. Not in the console, not anywhere. I've attempted to dig way down into the various `WKWebView` delegate methods, but it seems like `WKWebView` isn't even *trying* to do anything with these URLs.

However, if I attempt to open one of these URLs *in Safari*, Safari will ask me if I want to open the URL in my app, which will then load and handle the URL.

Has anyone else seen this? Or have any ideas of where to look to track this down?

I've tried:

- Removing and re-adding the URL scheme in my info.plist
- Changing the scheme to a new value, then removing it and adding it back in info.plist
- Deleting the app
- Rebooting my phone

Answer (score 0):

The issue has turned out to be something related to `Turbolinks`. Somehow there are situations where the page load event isn't firing, and Turbolinks then does not call code we need to activate some elements on the page.